# Como adicionar ToolBar e ViewPager no mesmo Layout

Tags: android-layout

Ao adicionar ambos componentes no XML de layout recebo o seguinte erro na linha de inicio do ViewPager:

```
error: Error parsing XML: unbound prefix
```

Layout:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/br.com.pixells.simuladorbr"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/toolbarListaJogos"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="#DC143C"
  app:subtitle="Teste"
  app:theme="@style/Theme.Abar.Widget"
  app:title="ToolBar" />
    
  <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager 
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/pager"  
   android:layout_width="match_parent"  
   android:layout_height="match_parent"  
   tools:context=".MainActivity" >  
  
  
    
<!--  
This title strip will display the currently visible page title, as well as the page  
titles for adjacent pages.  
-->  
    
   <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip  
    android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"  
    android:layout_width="match_parent"  
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    android:layout_gravity="top"  
    android:background="#33b5e5"  
    android:paddingBottom="4dp"  
    android:paddingTop="4dp" 
    android:textColor="#fff" />  
  
    
  </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager> 

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Não faltou adicionar o schema do `tools` (`xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"`)?

Comment: Deu certo, pq preciso adicionar esta linha?

Comment: Porque é preciso adicionar a referência ao schema do namespace `tools` para o parser poder interpretar essas tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta adicionar a referência ao schema do **namespace** `tools` no início do seu xml. Assim como os demais schemas:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/br.com.pixells.simuladorbr"
    <!-- Adicione a linha abaixo -->
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools
```

Essa inclusão é necessária para o **aapt** poder interpretar corretamente as tags do namespace `tools`.